# How to fix the Header of a table on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a table with several row.this table has scroll down and i am using of simplebar js file . how can i fix the header of table in scroll down. i wrote many codes an use fixed position to fix it. but did not worked correctly.
here is my snippet:

```js
;(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        factory(require('jquery'), window, document);
    } else {
        factory(window.jQuery, window, document);
    }
}(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var SCROLLBAR_WIDTH;

    function scrollbarWidth () {

        var tempEl  = $('<div class="scrollbar-width-tester" style="width:150px;height:300px;overflow-y:scroll;top:-9999px;left:-9999px;"><div style="height:100px;"></div>'),
            width   = 0,
            widthMinusScrollbars = 0;

        $('body').append(tempEl);

        width = $(tempEl).innerWidth(),
        widthMinusScrollbars = $('div', tempEl).innerWidth();

        tempEl.remove();

        return (width - widthMinusScrollbars);
    }

    var IS_WEBKIT = 'WebkitAppearance' in document.documentElement.style;

    function SimpleBar (element, options) {
        this.el = element,
        this.$el = $(element),
        this.$track,
        this.$scrollbar,
        this.dragOffset,
        this.flashTimeout,
        this.$contentEl         = this.$el,
        this.$scrollContentEl   = this.$el,
        this.scrollDirection    = 'vert',
        this.scrollOffsetAttr   = 'scrollTop',
        this.sizeAttr           = 'height',
        this.scrollSizeAttr     = 'scrollHeight',
        this.offsetAttr         = 'top';

        this.options = $.extend({}, SimpleBar.DEFAULTS, options);
        this.theme   = this.options.css;

        this.init();
    }

    SimpleBar.DEFAULTS = {
        wrapContent: true,
        autoHide: true,
        css: {
            container: 'simplebar',
            content: 'simplebar-content',
            scrollContent: 'simplebar-scroll-content',
            scrollbar: 'simplebar-scrollbar',
            scrollbarTrack: 'simplebar-track'
        }
    };

    SimpleBar.prototype.init = function () {
        // Measure scrollbar width
        if(typeof SCROLLBAR_WIDTH === 'undefined') {
            SCROLLBAR_WIDTH = scrollbarWidth();
        }

        // If scrollbar is a floating scrollbar, disable the plugin
        if(SCROLLBAR_WIDTH === 0) {
          this.$el.css('overflow', 'auto');

          return;
        }

        if (this.$el.data('simplebar-direction') === 'horizontal' || this.$el.hasClass(this.theme.container + ' horizontal')){
            this.scrollDirection    = 'horiz';
            this.scrollOffsetAttr   = 'scrollLeft';
            this.sizeAttr           = 'width';
            this.scrollSizeAttr     = 'scrollWidth';
            this.offsetAttr         = 'left';
        }

        if (this.options.wrapContent) {
            this.$el.wrapInner('<div class="' + this.theme.scrollContent + '"><div class="' + this.theme.content + '"></div></div>');
        }

        this.$contentEl = this.$el.find('.' + this.theme.content);

        this.$el.prepend('<div class="' + this.theme.scrollbarTrack + '"><div class="' + this.theme.scrollbar + '"></div></div>');
        this.$track = this.$el.find('.' + this.theme.scrollbarTrack);
        this.$scrollbar = this.$el.find('.' + this.theme.scrollbar);

        this.$scrollContentEl = this.$el.find('.' + this.theme.scrollContent);

        this.resizeScrollContent();

        if (this.options.autoHide) {
            this.$el.on('mouseenter', $.proxy(this.flashScrollbar, this));
        }

        this.$scrollbar.on('mousedown', $.proxy(this.startDrag, this));
        this.$scrollContentEl.on('scroll', $.proxy(this.startScroll, this));

        this.resizeScrollbar();

        if (!this.options.autoHide) {
            this.showScrollbar();
        }
    };


    /**
     * Start scrollbar handle drag
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.startDrag = function (e) {
        // Preventing the event's default action stops text being
        // selectable during the drag.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Measure how far the user's mouse is from the top of the scrollbar drag handle.
        var eventOffset = e.pageY;
        if (this.scrollDirection === 'horiz') {
            eventOffset = e.pageX;
        }
        this.dragOffset = eventOffset - this.$scrollbar.offset()[this.offsetAttr];

        $(document).on('mousemove', $.proxy(this.drag, this));
        $(document).on('mouseup', $.proxy(this.endDrag, this));
    };

    SimpleBar.prototype.drag = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Calculate how far the user's mouse is from the top/left of the scrollbar (minus the dragOffset).
        var eventOffset = e.pageY,
            dragPos     = null,
            dragPerc    = null,
            scrollPos   = null;

        if (this.scrollDirection === 'horiz') {
          eventOffset = e.pageX;
        }

        dragPos = eventOffset - this.$track.offset()[this.offsetAttr] - this.dragOffset;
        // Convert the mouse position into a percentage of the scrollbar height/width.
        dragPerc = dragPos / this.$track[this.sizeAttr]();
        // Scroll the content by the same percentage.
        scrollPos = dragPerc * this.$contentEl[0][this.scrollSizeAttr];

        this.$scrollContentEl[this.scrollOffsetAttr](scrollPos);
    };


    /**
     * End scroll handle drag
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.endDrag = function () {
        $(document).off('mousemove', this.drag);
        $(document).off('mouseup', this.endDrag);
    };


    /**
     * Resize scrollbar
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.resizeScrollbar = function () {
        if(SCROLLBAR_WIDTH === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var contentSize     = this.$contentEl[0][this.scrollSizeAttr],
            scrollOffset    = this.$scrollContentEl[this.scrollOffsetAttr](), // Either scrollTop() or scrollLeft().
            scrollbarSize   = this.$track[this.sizeAttr](),
            scrollbarRatio  = scrollbarSize / contentSize,
            // Calculate new height/position of drag handle.
            // Offset of 2px allows for a small top/bottom or left/right margin around handle.
            handleOffset    = Math.round(scrollbarRatio * scrollOffset) + 2,
            handleSize      = Math.floor(scrollbarRatio * (scrollbarSize - 2)) - 2;


        if (scrollbarSize < contentSize) {
            if (this.scrollDirection === 'vert'){
                this.$scrollbar.css({'top': handleOffset, 'height': handleSize});
            } else {
                this.$scrollbar.css({'left': handleOffset, 'width': handleSize});
            }
            this.$track.show();
        } else {
            this.$track.hide();
        }
    };


    /**
     * On scroll event handling
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.startScroll = function(e) {
        // Simulate event bubbling to root element
        this.$el.trigger(e);

        this.flashScrollbar();
    };


    /**
     * Flash scrollbar visibility
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.flashScrollbar = function () {
        this.resizeScrollbar();
        this.showScrollbar();
    };


    /**
     * Show scrollbar
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.showScrollbar = function () {
        this.$scrollbar.addClass('visible');

        if (!this.options.autoHide) {
            return;
        }
        if(typeof this.flashTimeout === 'number') {
            window.clearTimeout(this.flashTimeout);
        }

        this.flashTimeout = window.setTimeout($.proxy(this.hideScrollbar, this), 1000);
    };


    /**
     * Hide Scrollbar
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.hideScrollbar = function () {
        this.$scrollbar.removeClass('visible');
        if(typeof this.flashTimeout === 'number') {
            window.clearTimeout(this.flashTimeout);
        }
    };


    /**
     * Resize content element
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.resizeScrollContent = function () {
        if (IS_WEBKIT) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.scrollDirection === 'vert'){
            this.$scrollContentEl.width(this.$el.width()+SCROLLBAR_WIDTH);
            this.$scrollContentEl.height(this.$el.height());
        } else {
            this.$scrollContentEl.width(this.$el.width());
            this.$scrollContentEl.height(this.$el.height()+SCROLLBAR_WIDTH);
        }
    };


    /**
     * Recalculate scrollbar
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.recalculate = function () {
        this.resizeScrollContent();
        this.resizeScrollbar();
    };


    /**
     * Getter for original scrolling element
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.getScrollElement = function () {
        return this.$scrollContentEl;
    };


    /**
     * Getter for content element
     */
    SimpleBar.prototype.getContentElement = function () {
        return this.$contentEl;
    };


    /**
     * Data API
     */
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('[data-simplebar-direction]').each(function () {
            $(this).simplebar();
        });
    });


    /**
     * Plugin definition
     */
    var old = $.fn.simplebar;

    $.fn.simplebar = function (options) {
        var args = arguments,
            returns;

        // If the first parameter is an object (options), or was omitted,
        // instantiate a new instance of the plugin.
        if (typeof options === 'undefined' || typeof options === 'object') {
            return this.each(function () {

                // Only allow the plugin to be instantiated once,
                // so we check that the element has no plugin instantiation yet
                if (!$.data(this, 'simplebar')) { $.data(this, 'simplebar', new SimpleBar(this, options)); }
            });

        // If the first parameter is a string
        // treat this as a call to a public method.
        } else if (typeof options === 'string') {
            this.each(function () {
                var instance = $.data(this, 'simplebar');

                // Tests that there's already a plugin-instance
                // and checks that the requested public method exists
                if (instance instanceof SimpleBar && typeof instance[options] === 'function') {

                    // Call the method of our plugin instance,
                    // and pass it the supplied arguments.
                    returns = instance[options].apply( instance, Array.prototype.slice.call( args, 1 ) );
                }

                // Allow instances to be destroyed via the 'destroy' method
                if (options === 'destroy') {
                  $.data(this, 'simplebar', null);
                }
            });

            // If the earlier cached method
            // gives a value back return the value,
            // otherwise return this to preserve chainability.
            return returns !== undefined ? returns : this;
        }
    };

    $.fn.simplebar.Constructor = SimpleBar;


    /**
     * No conflict
     */
    $.fn.simplebar.noConflict = function () {
        $.fn.simplebar = old;
        return this;
    };

}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<style>
.simplebar, [data-simplebar-direction] {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Trigger native scrolling for mobile, if not supported, plugin is used. */
}

.simplebar .simplebar-scroll-content,
[data-simplebar-direction] .simplebar-scroll-content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* hide browser scrollbar on IE10+ */
}

/* hide browser scrollbar on Webkit (Safari & Chrome) */
.simplebar-scroll-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

[data-simplebar-direction="horizontal"] .simplebar-scroll-content,
.simplebar.horizontal .simplebar-scroll-content {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.simplebar-track {
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 11px;
}

.simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    min-height: 10px;
    width: 7px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    background: #6c6e71;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
}
.simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar.visible {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";
    opacity: 0.7;
}

[data-simplebar-direction="horizontal"] .simplebar-track,
.simplebar.horizontal .simplebar-track {
    top: auto;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: 11px;
}
[data-simplebar-direction="horizontal"] .simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar,
.simplebar.horizontal .simplebar-track .simplebar-scrollbar {
    right: auto;
    top: 2px;
    height: 7px;
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 10px;
    width: auto;
}
.demo1 {margin: 10px 0;width: 250px;height: 300px;}

</style>


</head>

  

<body>

<style>
tr {height:200px;}
thead{background:pink;}
</style>
<div class="demo1 divtable" data-simplebar-direction="vertical">
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">title 1</th>
      <th scope="col">title 2</th>
      <th scope="col">title 3</th>
      <th scope="col">title 3</th>
      <th scope="col">title 3</th>
 
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
    </tr>
    
       <tr>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
    </tr>
    
       <tr>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
      <td aria-label="">123456789</td>
    </tr>


</table>

</div>

      





 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h1>
<table class="blue">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colonne 1</th>
      <th>Colonne 2</th>
      <th>Colonne 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h1>
<table class="purple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colonne 1</th>
      <th>Colonne 2</th>
      <th>Colonne 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h1>
```

Try this link:-https://codepen.io/jgx/pen/wiIGc